# When setting absolute positioning to left:50%, page doubles

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm setting the buttons `#login` and `#register` to have `position: absolute;`, and a value of `left: 50%`, but whenever I do this, all of the content on the page doubles below the original page.

[image]
[image]

```css
    header {
        background-image:url("");
        pading:1vh 2vw;
        height:98vh;
        width:96vw;
    }
    
    .title {
        position:absolute;
        left:5px;
        top:5px;
    }
    
    #register {
        background-color:#66ff66;
        color:#595959;
    }
    
    #login {
        background-color:#4dd2ff;
        color:#595959;
    }
    
    #login, #register {
        width:300px;
        height:35px;
        border:0;
        border-radius:8px;
        position:absolute;
        left:50%;
    }
```

Comment: You have two closing `</header>` tags...I suspect that might be related.

Answer (score 2):

**Problems**

- you have  a closed `</header>` twice in your code
- your `id`'s aren't unique, and most likely because you doubled/repeated your code
- you have a typo in your css should be `padding` not `pading`
- plus you should add `position:relative` to parent where your child has `position:absolute`otherwise will be  out of flow regards to DOM

**Notes**

- avoid using inline styles
- don't use multiple  `&nbsp;` to create space, instead use `margin/padding`
- reset `margin` in `body` to avoid horizontal scrollbar

```css
body {
  margin:0
}
header {
  background-image: url("");
  padding: 1vh 2vw;
  height: 98vh;
  width: 96vw;
}
#register {
  background-color: #66ff66;
  color: #595959;
}
#login {
  background-color: #4dd2ff;
  color: #595959;
}
#login,
#register {
  width: 300px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}
/* new */

.p-header {
  position: relative
}
#content-header-home h1 span:first-of-type {
  color: #000
}
#content-header-home h1 span:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: #737373
}
#content-header-home h1 span:last-of-type {
  color: #ccc
}
#changing {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="content-header-home">
    <h1><span>Team</span><span>Builder</span> <span>.com</span></h1>
    <p class="p-header">Your<span id="changing"> is just a few steps away!</span>
    </p>
    <div class="buttons-home" id="buttons-home">
      <button id="register">Create an Account</button>
      <p>OR</p>
      <button id="login">Login</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End header content -->
</header>
```